# Display page view inside page.tpl.php drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a file called page--advertsindex.tpl.php.. Now what i want to do is display that page inside the content region of page.tpl.php..

page--advertsindex.tpl.php contains the HTML which need's to be rendered in the content region of page.tpl but what it does currently when i navigate to my_drupal_site/advertsindex it only show's the html of page--advertsindex, not the page.tpl.php file and the page--advertsindex in the content region..

How can i do this? or is there a different way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You may consider using http://drupal.stackexchange.com for these questions; Your question is more about the usage of Drupal then about coding. Not that it is off-topic here, but that drupal.stackexchange.com is an even more on-topic.

Comment: Aaah yes, im very new to stackexchange did not know there was a subdomain for drupal... thanks for the tip :)! i'll make sure to go there if i have another drupal related question!

Answer (score 1):

Any `page--<identifier>.tpl.php` will be used **instead** of `page.tpl.php` for the url `/identifier`. That is by design and the entire purpose of this system. This can be extended for deeper paths too: `page--foo-bar-baz.tpl.php` for `/foo/bar/baz`.

If you want certain content to appear on `/identifier`, you have two options: Conditionally include the content or copy the content. What to choose depends on your situation.

Conditionally include: inside `page.tpl.php`:

```
<div class="footer">
  <?php if (arg(0) == "advertsindex"): ?>
    <?php print theme("advertsindex_disclaimer"); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Overrides: introduce a `page--advertsindex.tpl.php`:

```
<div id="content">
  <?php print $content ?>
</div>
```

When to choose what:

Only use conditional includes or conditional rendering when:

- The content to be included or excluded is small and shared. Patterns like `[large 20+ line of frontpage HTML][normal HTML] are very bad.
- The content to be included needs all sorts of fancy new variables pulled in. Patterns like  are really bad. Drupals theme system is push (theme gets variables from modules) and never pull (theme requests parameters at modules).

In all other cases you'd use the overrides. And yes, that will include a lot of duplication, but that is by design and accepted as the default practice in Drupal. To avoid having to modify some HTML in 20+ files, "split" or "copy" them as late as possible.

A rule of thumb is that a conditional should be a few lines only and never require variables that are not available in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If **advertsindex** is would be one of your content type then you have to create node--advertsindex.tpl.php file instead of page--advertsindex.tpl.php. Or If you wont to display some content in the page.tpl.php page, then it is better to copy all code of page.tpl.php into YOUR-Custom_page.tpl.php and put your code inside the content section of YOUR-Custom_page.tpl.php.

I think it helps.

Comment: I have that right now. Im using adverts-index.tpl.php but it won't let me show any other things. like a block in the sidebar_right